# Capturar un dato de json desde php

Tags: javascript, php, array, json

Amigos tengo este problema tengo un json y quiero pasar esos datos a php para ello tengo el siguiente codigo

```
{
  "event": "transaction.updated",
  "data": {
    "transaction": {
        "id": "1234-1610641025-49201",
        "amount_in_cents": 4490000,
        "reference": "MZQ3X2DE2SMX",
        "customer_email": "juan.perez@gmail.com",
        "currency": "COP",
        "payment_method_type": "NEQUI",
        "redirect_url": "https://mitienda.com.co/pagos/redireccion",
        "status": "APPROVED",
        "shipping_address": null,
        "payment_link_id": null,
        "payment_source_id": null
      }
  },
  "environment": "prod",
  "signature": {
    "properties": [
      "transaction.id",
      "transaction.status",
      "transaction.amount_in_cents"
    ],
    "checksum": "3476DDA50F64CD7CBD160689640506FEBEA93239BC524FC0469B2C68A3CC8BD0"
  },
  "timestamp": 1530291411,
  "sent_at":  "2018-07-20T16:45:05.000Z"
}


<?php 
    //desde esta parte estoy llamando la ruta del archivo
    $content_current = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $json_current = json_decode($content_current, true);
    $logFile = fopen("log.txt", 'a') or die("Error creando archivo");  //ABRO LOG
    fwrite($logFile, "\n".date("d/m/Y H:i:s")." ------- diego") or die("Error escribiendo en el archivo");
    fwrite($logFile, "\n".date("d/m/Y H:i:s")." -------".$json_current['data']['transaction'('id')]) or die("Error escribiendo en el archivo");
    fclose($logFile);
    ?>
```

1. Quiero capturar los datos con php y escribirlos en un archivo .log.txt. para ello tengo este codigo pero no me sale nada.
   Solo me sale diego y del otro me sale array.  y necesito coger cada dato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si tu JSON queda guardado en un archivo independiente, debes llamarlo por el nombre.

```
$content_current = file_get_contents('myruta/myjson.json');
```

Segundo, es mejor usar el llamado simple para los objetos.

```
$json_current['data']['transaction']['id']
```

Siempre imprime los resultados de cada linea para saber donde esta el error.

```
echo $content_current = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json_current = json_decode($content_current, true);
print_r($json_current);
```

También puedes usar herramientas en linea, para validar que tu JSON tenga la estructura correcta.

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Como lo paso a una variable de php

Comment: como te comenta @ElJavinci el json debe estar en un archivo independiente. Me parece que el problema que tienes es que lo escribes en el archivo como texto plano, y luego quieres leerlo desde el mismo archivo en la parte de php, y eso asi no se puede hacer. Debes enviar ese json (bien por ajax, por postman, desde otra app) y leerlo con los metodos de archivo, o con $_FILES (como mejor sea), o si acaso meter el json entre comillas simples y asignarlo a una variable. Y a partir de ahi tratarlo